# How can I delete duplicates in Oracle SQL, where a tuple is a duplicate if the same values are interchanged in columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, tuples

Tuples of the following format are all considered duplicates:

```
A, B, C
A, C, B
B, C, A
B, A, C
C, A, B
C, B, A
```

How can I delete duplicates of a tuple (like these) in an Oracle SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy with two columns:

```
select distinct least(c1,c2), greatest(c1,c2)
from the_table;
```

The above can then be used for a `delete` statement:

```
delete from foo
where rowid not in (select min(rowid)
                    from foo
                    group by least(c1,c2), greatest(c1,c2));
```

With three columns, it's a bit more complicated:

```
select distinct 
         least(c1,c2,c3) as one,
         case 
           when c1 > least(c1,c2,c3) and c1 < greatest(c1,c2,c3) then c1
           when c2 > least(c1,c2,c3) and c2 < greatest(c1,c2,c3) then c2
           when c3 > least(c1,c2,c3) and c3 < greatest(c1,c2,c3) then c3
         end as two,
         greatest(c1,c2,c3) as three
from foo;
```

And consequently the delete statement is a bit more complicate:

```
delete from foo 
where rowid not in (
      select min(rowid)
      from foo
      group by least(c1,c2,c3),
               case 
                 when c1 > least(c1,c2,c3) and c1 < greatest(c1,c2,c3) then c1
                 when c2 > least(c1,c2,c3) and c2 < greatest(c1,c2,c3) then c2
                 when c3 > least(c1,c2,c3) and c3 < greatest(c1,c2,c3) then c3
               end,
               greatest(c1,c2,c3))
```

You didn't specify *which* row should be left in the table. The above will pick a "random" one (based on the rowid).